# Confusion on Big-O

Tags: notation, algorithms, asymptotics

So I have to prove that $\sqrt n = O(n/\log^2 n)$. I've never come across something with division.
Would this be the same as proving $(\log^2 n )\sqrt n = O(n)$? Or if I were to do it with

$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)/g(x)$ would I bring the $\log^2 n$ to the numerator?

Comment: You need to show that there is a $C>0$ such that $
\sqrt n  \le C\frac{n}{{\log ^2 n}}
$ for all large values of $n$. The inequality is equivalent to $
\log ^2 n \le C\sqrt n$.

Comment: would it just be solving  limx→∞log^2n/√n after simplifying?

Comment: What is $x$? It would be enough to show that the limit exists and is finite. Do you knwo that $\log w\leq w$ for all $w>0$? Because then $$
\log ^2 n = (4\log (n^{1/4} ))^2  \le (4n^{1/4} )^2  = 16\sqrt n 
$$ for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: I'm sorry it's limn→∞log^2n/√n

Comment: Your explanation makes sense I think I got it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$f(n)=\mathcal{O}(g(n))\iff \limsup_{n\to+\infty}\frac{|f(n)|}{g(n)}<+\infty. $$
Setting

- $f:n\mapsto f(n)=\sqrt{n}$.
- $g:n\mapsto g(n)=\frac{n}{\log^{2}n}$.

Since $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{|f(n)|}{g(n)}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{|\sqrt{n}|}{n/\log^{2}n}=0.$$
The result is follows.

Comment: I understand that part the trouble I was having was solving the limit. If you could show the steps.

Comment: Equivalence in 2 definition at second line we can have only when $g=0$ have not $\infty$ as condensation point.